Is the construction "record somebody to-infinitive" possible?
Is the construction "record somebody to-infinitive" possible?
None of the dictionaries I have consulted has an example sentence that uses such a construction, but I guess it is possible.

Alice recorded Paul to witness a triangular UFO. [my sentence]

Thank you.

Nope. What is it supposed to mean? Did Alice or Paul witness the UFO?

Alice recorded that Paul witnessed a triangular UFO.

Alice recorded Paul's account of his UFO sighting. Clearly she did not record the UFO sighting itself, the actual witnessing, for then you would say that she recorded a UFO.

Thank you, @TimR. "Alice recorded Paul's account of his UFO sighting" is what I need.


Can we use record plus infinitive?

No, that's not the way the expression works. Generally record is a transitive verb, so it takes a direct object.

The technician recorded the live concert.
The TV channels recorded the football match.

In your example, the recording is of an action. This is dealt with as a participle, not an infinitive. The recording happens while the action is occurring.

Alice recorded Paul witnessing a triangular UFO.


And "the action" is not the story Paul tells later about the UFO sighting but the appearance of the UFO itself, and for that Alice must be present when the UFO appears.Just adding that clarification in case a learner looks at a definition of the verb "witness" that says it means "to testify".
